# Download Note Attachment via JavaScript from D365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Does anyone have some JavaScript examples on how to download Notes attachments in D365?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please go through following link https://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2016/09/29/downloading-dynamics-crm-attachments-with-javascript/